# Azure Api App - IP Restriction - Cannot get correct client IP address and/or hostname

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api

I have built a .NET Web API and deployed it to Azure as an API App. I have tried to implement access restriction to the API by either IP address or hostname. I have attempted this in a couple of ways:

1. By implementing the OwinMiddleware class and checking the requests RemoteIpAddress and Host against a whitelist. These values I fetch by

   ```
   var ip = context.Request.RemoteIpAddress;
   var host = context.Request.Host.ToString();
   ```

where context is of type IOwinContext

2. In the controller by checking the following:

   ```
   var ipAddress = Request.GetOwinContext().Request.RemoteIpAddress;
   var host = Request.GetOwinContext().Request.Host;
   //Also tried 
   //var ipAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]
   ```
3. In the web.config by specifying allowed IP addresses:

```html
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
          <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false" denyAction="Forbidden">
            <add allowed="true" ipAddress="xxx.xx.xx.xx" subnetMask="255.255.255.0"/>
          </ipSecurity>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
```

If I do not add the Web Apis own IP address to the allowed list of IPs, then I get a forbidden error. When I add the Web Apis IP address to the allowed list, then any client can send requests to the api.

I then call my web api locally using Postman as well as from an instance of another web project which is hosted on a separate Azure VM. This VM isn't located in the same resource group as the Web Api.

The strange thing is that no matter what I try, the request host and ip address always appear to be the Web Api's own host and ip address. So it appears as if the request to the web api is internal, and hasn't come from an external source. So I never get the IP/hostname of my local machine or Azure VM coming up in the request details.

I really don't understand how this can happen. Am I going about getting the clients IP and hostname the wrong way? Or is there something happening with the internal routing in the Web Api that makes me lose the original client request information? Or am I misunderstanding something fundamentally here?

Edit:

After some more testing, I found that if I used

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]
```

then I would get the right original client IP address in a list of IP addresses (it was normally the first IP address in the list). However I cannot see a way of getting the correct client hostname.

However, I would still like to know why I cannot fetch the correct client information using for example Owin or web.config IP restrictions? Is this an Azure/Web Api thing? Or do I need to set more request headers from my proxy where I call the web api?

Answer (score 1):

After some more testing, I found that if I used

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]
```

then I would get the right original client IP address in a list of IP addresses (it was normally the first IP address in the list). However I cannot see a way of getting the correct client hostname.

Comment: I did the same thing and I can successfully get the IPv4 address
But I do not see for any of the requests the IPv6 been sent?
Do I have to enable something on the azure service side? Is this a known limitation of the azure cloud services?
thank you